# thymeleaf iteration inside td and special selections of values

Tags: javascript, spring, html, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf in a spring boot project. I have a list of items and i want to place them in a table.

This list has to be separated in 4 columns. The items have and id that refers to the specific column.

So i have a table and in the body i want to set different "tds" in one "tr". In each "td" i want to iterate the list, find the item with the correct id and set a specific qty in an input.

The list comes from db so i has only the items that have value so if something is going to be zero this item will not exist.

The problem comes when i want to place zero when i do not have the item.

I wanted to be done with thymeleaf only and not add a javascript function to set later the values.

Write now i am using this code:

```
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td th:each="extraWork: ${ExtraWorkList}" class="BRtd" th:if="${extraWork.extraWorkCategory.id==1}"><input type="number" class="bReal" th:name="test2" th:value="${extraWork.qty}"></td>    
                        <td th:each="extraWork: ${ExtraWorkList}" class="BRtd" th:if="${extraWork.extraWorkCategory.id==2}"><input type="number" class="bReal" th:name="test3" th:value="${extraWork.qty}"></td>    
                        <td th:each="extraWork: ${ExtraWorkList}" class="BRtd" th:if="${extraWork.extraWorkCategory.id==3}"><input type="number" class="bReal" th:name="test4" th:value="${extraWork.qty}"></td>    
                        <td th:each="extraWork: ${ExtraWorkList}" class="BRtd" th:if="${extraWork.extraWorkCategory.id==4}"><input type="number" class="bReal" th:name="test5" th:value="${extraWork.qty}"></td>    
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

But this does not do create input if the item of specific id does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Hi change your approach ,

```
   <table th:if="${ExtraWorkList.length > 0}">

                .................

                <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="${index: #numbers.sequence(0, ExtraWorkList.length, 4)}">
                        <td class="BRtd"><input type="number" class="bReal" th:name="test2" th:value="${ExtraWorkList[index].qty}"></td>    
                        <td class="BRtd" th:if="${ExtraWorkList[index + 1] != null}"><input type="number" class="bReal" th:name="test3" th:value="${ExtraWorkList[index + 1].qty}"></td>    
                        <td class="BRtd" th:if="${ExtraWorkList[index + 2] != null}"><input type="number" class="bReal" th:name="test4" th:value="${ExtraWorkList[index + 2].qty}"></td>    
                        <td class="BRtd" th:if="${ExtraWorkList[index + 3] != null}"><input type="number" class="bReal" th:name="test5" th:value="${ExtraWorkList[index + 3].qty}"></td>    
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

will do the job.

Comment: can you explain it please cause i do not exactly get it?

Comment: numbers.sequence will increment by 4 so the index will go by 0,4,8,12 so on.for first row will have 0,1,2,3 and second row will have 4,5,6,7 and so on. let say your list has 13 then elements  there will be 4 rows  ([0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11],[12]).

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with [collection selection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-selection) and then check for a null object.  This should work for you:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td th:with="extraWork=${ExtraWorkList.^[extraWorkCategory.id==1]}" class="BRtd"><input type="number" class="bReal" th:name="test2" th:value="${extraWork == null ? 0 : extraWork.qty}" /></td>    
        <td th:with="extraWork=${ExtraWorkList.^[extraWorkCategory.id==2]}" class="BRtd"><input type="number" class="bReal" th:name="test3" th:value="${extraWork == null ? 0 : extraWork.qty}" /></td>    
        <td th:with="extraWork=${ExtraWorkList.^[extraWorkCategory.id==3]}" class="BRtd"><input type="number" class="bReal" th:name="test4" th:value="${extraWork == null ? 0 : extraWork.qty}" /></td>    
        <td th:with="extraWork=${ExtraWorkList.^[extraWorkCategory.id==4]}" class="BRtd"><input type="number" class="bReal" th:name="test5" th:value="${extraWork == null ? 0 : extraWork.qty}" /></td>    
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

You could simplify this even further, if you wanted (although it's getting a little complex now).  Something like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(1,4)}" th:with="extraWork=${ExtraWorkList.^[extraWorkCategory.id==__${i}__]}" class="BRtd"><input type="number" class="bReal" th:name="|test${i+1}|" th:value="${extraWork == null ? 0 : extraWork.qty}" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```